# Trying to get location_profile to show location.name in __str__ (django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following 2 models:

```
class LocationProfile(models.Model):
    units                   = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    location_notes          = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_occupied             = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location.name

class Location(models.Model):
    organization            = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=None)
    location_profile        = models.OneToOneField(LocationProfile, on_delete=None)
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address1                = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I am trying to get `LocationProfile` to show the name of the `Location` but the error is:
`LocationProfile has no location`.

Each `Location` has 1 `Location Profile`, and if possible, I would like to be able to select the `Location Profile` from the `Location` dropdown in the django admin (as opposed to going to `Location Profile` and selecting the `Location`.)

Comment: Why a one2one field here ? Do you really need two distinct models ?

Comment: probably you cant, even `related_name` shouldn't work for that.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers there's more fields in the both of the models than what I put.

Comment: @ashwinbande If it's not possible, than ok. I'll just use the ID or something instead. I thought using `location` would be available since it's a 1-to-1.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, based on @ashwin-bandes suggestion.

I've modified the models to look as such (might be a little overkill, but I wanted to ensure it worked):

```
class LocationProfile(models.Model):
    units                   = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    location_notes          = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_occupied             = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            loc = Location.objects.get(location_profile=self.id)
            return loc.name
        except Location.DoesNotExist:
            return '%s' % self.id    

class Location(models.Model):
        organization            = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=None)
        location_profile        = models.OneToOneField(
                                    LocationProfile, 
                                    on_delete=None, 
                                    related_name="location", 
                                    related_query_name="location",
                                    primary_key=True,
                                    db_column='id'
                                )
```

Basically, it will initially create the `LocationProfile` within `Location`, but `Location` will only see the `LocationProfile` ID since LP has not been set to a company yet (or in the event it is, it will set it back to using just the profile ID). If the profile is set to a company, the user will see the `Location`'s name instead of the profile ID. Might not be the most elegant on the admin's side, but it's workable for what I need.